# Why mqtt with an autorun script.py can't stabilized the connection with the broker?

Tags: python-3.x, bash, mqtt

I am trying to run automatically a script in python. This script manage several LEDs and communicate via MQTT.

If I try to run the script via shell (no autorun) my connection work without any problem.

If I try to autorun the script, it starts correctly but the connection with the broker keep going up, down, up, down, up,... in an infinite loop. It can not establish the connection.

The autorun script is loaded in /etc/profile -> sudo python3 script/path.py

What could cause this problem?

- recap:

  via shell -> work all good, no problem

  via autorun -> start ok, connection up-down-up-down-....
- Script in python, connection to broker:

```py
def Connect(client,broker,port,keepalive,run_forever=False):
    #"""Attempts connection set delay to >1 to keep trying
    #but at longer intervals  """
    connflag=False
    delay=5

    print('--------------------------------')
    print("connecting " + client_id)
    badcount=0 # counter for bad connection attempts
    while not connflag:
        logging.info("connecting to broker "+str(broker))
        print("connecting to broker "+str(broker)+":"+str(port))
        print("Attempts ",badcount)
        try:
            res=client.connect(broker,port,keepalive)      #connect to broker
            if res==0:
                print('--------------------------------')
                print("Connection established")
                print('--------------------------------')
                connflag=True
                return 0
            else:
                logging.debug("connection failed.")
                print('--------------------------------')
                badcount += 1
                if badcount>=3 and not run_forever: 
                    raise SystemExit #give up

                elif run_forever and badcount<3:
                    delay=5
                else:
                    delay=3
[...........................................................]
[..................other stuff.................]
[...........................................................]


def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print('--------------------------------')
    logging.debug("Connected flags"+str(flags)+"result code "  + str(rc) + "client RPi Giulio")
    if rc == 0:
        print("Connected OK. Returned code = ", rc)
        print('--------------------------------')
        client.connected_flag  = True
        client.publish(connected_topic,1,retain=True)

    else:
        print("Bad connection. Returned code = ", rc)
        print('--------------------------------')
        client.bad_connection_flag = True
```

- Broker instance shows:

  RPiGiulio/Connection/status 0

  RPiGiulio/Connection/status 1

  RPiGiulio/Connection/status 0

  RPiGiulio/Connection/status 1

  RPiGiulio/Connection/status 0

  RPiGiulio/Connection/status 1

  [..............................]
- Autorun script command:

  Write @ sudo nano /etc/profile

  sudo python3 /home/pi/..../main.py &

SOLUTION: CRONTAB https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/auto-run-python-programs-on-the-raspberry-pi/

Comment: Without the script or the logs from the broker we can only guess at what the problem might be.

Comment: I've edited the question: added the connection script and instance broker example.

Comment: run `ps -efc | grep python3` to see how many instances of the client you have running.

Comment: Also what is the time interval between the connection status messages? I don't see where you are starting the client network loop.

Comment: I have 4 instances open.. 2instances " sudo python3 /home/pi/Desktop/LightStim/main.py " and other 2 instances "python3 /home/pi/Desktop/LightStim/main.py"

That's the problem, how can i fix it?

Comment: I've used "crontab" instead .profile and it works without any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments this is purely a guess based on the very limited information available.

The usual reason for a client to keep connecting/disconnecting is because you have multiple clients with the same clientid.

You can only ever have 1 client at a time connected to the broker with a given clientid, if a second client connects then the first will be kicked off. If the first client then tries to reconnect it will then kick the second client off and start the sequence again.

Because `.profile` is run for every login shell you could end up many instances of the client running.

You need to make sure that you only ever start one copy of the client and it has a unique clientid.

Comment: I've edited the question: added the connection script and instance broker example.
The client ID is unique. I had this error some times ago and I fixed it. The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: "Because .profile is run for every login shell you could end up many instances of the client running"

Could you exaplain how it can start more than 1 shell with the script? I mean the command and the script is just one.

Comment: But `.profile` is run every time you login, so if you have logged in more than once, it will have started more than one instance of the client.